# invalid operands of types const char*

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a new `const char* b` by adding a new string "hello" to original `const char* a`:

```
const char* a = some_code_here;
const char* b = (a + "_hello").c_str();
```

And the error I get is:

```
error: invalid operands of types const char* and const char [6] to binary operator+
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: The compiler is already telling you you're doing something wrong. So what is your question?

Comment: Character pointers don't have the `.c_str()` method; there a fundamental type and don't have any methods.

Comment: Adding character pointers together will not do what you expect.  Consider this like adding your mailing address with a friends mailing address; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @david You are doing all right. Simply throw this compiler and write your own!:)

Comment: @101010 in fact this is more c styled code. All the modern OO languages has + operator to concat strings, including c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to strings, that is `std::string`.
Repeat after me, *forget about using char or C-style strings*.
As you have demonstrated, this is one of many issues.

Did I say switch to `std::string`?

Your `char *` is a pointer.  Nothing more, nothing less, a pointer.  A pointer to a single `char`; not a structure.  The `char` data type doesn't have methods.

Switch to `std::string`.

You can add (concatenate) `std::string`.

Switch to `std::string`.

The `std::string` has the `c_str()` method.  Don't use unless you understand the consequences; completely.

Comment: Excellent, this could be a standard answer to most c-string related questions in C++!

Answer (score 3):

You can't arbitrarily add `const char*` in C++. These objects are just pointers to a contiguous section of memory, so adding them doesn't make sense. Instead, you should use the `std::string` class:

```
std::string a = "something";
std::string b = a + "_hello";
```